# Count every PO No & tell the PO Number

Tags: sql

Above is `POAmendment` Table which has data of each revised made in PO. Eg PONO 201 is 3 times revised, 301 is 1 time revised and 401 is 2 times revised respectively.
You Task is to find Latest Revised POAmendment Of Each PO.

I am not creating any local Table in Database.

```
POAmendmentNo   PONo    Dated       AmendmentNo

100             201     01-Apr-19   0

101             201     02-Apr-19   1

102             201     03-Apr-19   2

103             301     01-Apr-19   0

104             401     01-Apr-19   0

105             401     02-Apr-19   1
```

Below is what I've tried so far,

```
select PONo,Dated,AmendmentNo from POAmendment 

where PONo in

(select PAD.PONo  from POAmendment PAD 

group by PAD.PONo     

having COUNT(1) =1 

orderby Dated desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
select t1.POAmendmentNo, t1.PONo, t1.Dated, t1.AmendmentNo
from yourTable t1
where t1.AmendmentNo =
    (
    select max(t2.AmendmentNo)
    from yourTable t2
    where t2.PONo = t1.PONo
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AmendmentNo` column actually appears to keep track of what record was amended most recently.  So, we can try using it here:

```
SELECT po1.*
FROM POAmendment po1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PONo, MAX(AmendmentNo) AS max_no
    FROM POAmendment
    GROUP BY PONo
) po2
    ON po1.PONo = po2.PONo AND
       po1.AmendmentNo = po2.max_no;
```

If your version of SQL supports `ROW_NUMBER`, then we can use that instead:

```
SELECT POAmendmentNo, PONo, Dated, AmendmentNo
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PONo ORDER BY AmendmentNo DESC) rn
    FROM POAmendment
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```